# Does Tradingview allow for only one EOD exit with multiple open long positions?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Daily bars...

I'm trying to do a simple study for long only, take all signals as they happen, exit all positions at last bar on chart ONLY. I can get the condition for taking the position to happen just fine, but it only happens ONCE, I need EVERY signal to be taken. Need a little help here. GPT wasn't much help either.

I tried to look for similar strategies to see how that code worked (couldn't find any!) and I about wore ChatGPT out.. I was expecting to see many positions executed on the chart, with one exit for ALL positions on the last daily bar.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.